# System of equations involving complex eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Consider the following equation:
$$ x_{n+2}-2ax_{n+1}+x_n=0$$
a) Define a new auxiliary variable $y_n = x_{n+1}$ and rewrite the previous equation as a discrete, two-equation dynamical system.
b) What can be said about the asymptotic behaviour of $x_n$ when $n \to \infty$ depending on the parameter $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

When doing this, I'm left with the system:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n+1}= y_n \\ 
y_{n+1}=-x_n+2ay_n \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Which can be written as
$$\pmatrix{x_{n+1}\\y_{n+1}}=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&2a}\pmatrix{x_n\\y_n}$$
$$\begin{matrix}\end{matrix}$$

But here's my question: the characteristic polynomial p($\lambda$)=$\lambda^2-2a\lambda+1$, and therefore $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=2a$ and $\lambda_1\lambda_2 =1$. (I don't know if I'm skipping any restrictions on the eigenvalues, apart from the fact that they've got to have the same sign). The eigenvalues are:

$$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{2a\pm\sqrt{4a^2-4}}{2}={a\pm\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$.

So, if i let $a \in ]-1,1[$, then the eigenvalues take the form $\lambda_{1,2}={a\pm i\sqrt{1-a^2} = \alpha \pm i\beta}$. Since the eigenvalues are complex numbers, I can take the matrix to one of Jordan canonical forms:

$$A=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&2a}=r\pmatrix{\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha}$$

The problem is that I get that $r = a^2 + (\sqrt{1-a^2})^2 = a^2+1-a^2=1$ for all $a \in ]-1,1[$, but when I plot the dynamical system when $a \neq 0$, I get that $(0,0)$ is a repulsor fixed point for the system: as $n \to \infty$, when I raise $A^n$ I get a $r^n$ factor that diverges, which means $|r|>1$. Any ideas of why this happens? I've been struggling with this all day and I have absolutely no idea where to begin.

Comment: Have you tried using $\,a=1/2?\,$ The dynamical system is periodic with period $6.\,$You may be using floating point which is subject to rounding errors. In effect, $|r|$ is slightly bigger than $1$ because of this.

Comment: @Somos [link](https://prnt.sc/ouwdlt) This is what I get when I plot it (I know it's not a continuous problem, but in the limit I was taught that the behaviour of the system should be the same). I replaced $a=1/2$ and $(0,0)$ is still a repulsor point, when algebraically $r=1$ for all $a \in ]-1,1[$.

Comment: What you are plotting is the phase portrait of the ODE $x' = y, y' = -x + 2ay.\,$ You **don't** want to do that. You want a **discrete** dynamical system. The corrsponding ODE would be $x' = by, y' = -bx.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n=t^n$, then you get $$t^2-2at+1=0 \Rightarrow _{1,2}=a\pm\sqrt{a^2-1}.$$
So the solution of your recurrence relation (equation) is
$$x_n=C_1 t_1^n + C_2 t_2^n \Rightarrow x_n= C_1 (a+\sqrt{a^2-1})^n+ C_2 (a-\sqrt{a^2-1})^n.$$
Suppose $a^2<1$, then let $\sqrt{a^2-1}=ib =i \sqrt{1-a^2}.$ So
$$x_n=C_1 (a+ib)^n + C_2 (a-ib)^n.$$
As $|a+ib|=1$,we write $a\pm ib= \exp(i\theta)$, then
$$x_n=C_1 e^{in\theta} + C_2 e^{-in\theta}=(C_1+C_2) \cos n\theta + i(C_1-C_2) \sin n\theta. $$
Finally $$x_n= D_1 \cos n\theta+ C_2 \sin n\theta$$, where $$\theta =\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a} \right)$$

Comment: The thing is that I'm asking about why, if a is in ]-1,1[ and therefore both eigenvalues are complex, the radius (which algebraically is equal to 1) does not coincide with what I'm seeing when I plot the system, trying $a=1/2$ makes every initial condition $x_0$ diverge even though the eigenvalues are complex.

Comment: @Bastian Ignacio Herrera I have added more stuff, se my answer again.